# Приведение double к short в Java

Tags: java, типы

При попытке привести `double x` к типу `short`

```
double x = 389889877779.89;

System.out.println((short)x);
```

на консоль выводится `-1`. Как это происходит на уровне битов? Неплохо было бы это визуализировать.

Comment: Дам совет как проверяется поведение функции? Смотрят на изменения, и вам совет задайте различные значения вы увидите что будет происходить.

Answer (score 2):

**[Явные преобразования](https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/2.2.php)**

**Потеря данных при преобразовании**

При применении явных преобразований мы можем столкнуться с потерей данных. Например, в следующем коде у нас не возникнет никаких проблем:

```
int a = 5;
byte b = (byte) a;
System.out.println(b);      // 5
```

Число 5 вполне укладывается в диапазон значений типа byte, поэтому после преобразования переменная b будет равна 5. Но что будет в следующем случае:

```
int a = 258;
byte b = (byte) a;
System.out.println(b);      // 2
```

Результатом будет число 2. В данном случае число 258 вне диапазона для типа byte (от -128 до 127), поэтому произойдет усечение значения. Почему результатом будет именно число 2?

Число a, которое равно 258, в двоичном системе будет равно 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000010. Значения типа byte занимают в памяти только 8 бит. Поэтому двоичное представление числа int усекается до 8 правых разрядов, то есть 00000010, что в десятичной системе дает число 2.

**Усечение рациональных чисел до целых**

При преобразовании значений с плавающей точкой к целочисленным значениям, происходит усечение дробной части:

```
double a = 56.9898;
int b = (int)a;
```

Здесь значение числа b будет равно 56, несмотря на то, что число 57 было бы ближе к 56.9898. Чтобы избежать подобных казусов, надо применять функцию округления, которая есть в математической библиотеке Java:

```
double a = 56.9898;
int b = (int)Math.round(a);
```

Так вот в вашем случае происходит следующее. Преобразование в целое и потеря данных.

Примеры для тестов

```
double d = 389889877779.89;
System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString((long) d));//           101101011000111001111110110011100010011
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString((int) (long) d));//         11000111001111110110011100010011
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString((int) d));//                 1111111111111111111111111111111
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString((short) (long) d));//                        110011100010011
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString((short) d));//              11111111111111111111111111111111
```

Comment: Если действовать по вашей логике, то число 389889877779 (убрали дробную часть) будет переведено в двоичную СС как 101101011000111001111110110011100010011. Тип short занимает 16 бит, тогда возьмём 0110011100010011. Каким образом нам теперь прийти к -1 из этих битов?

Comment: Добавил примеров для размышления

Comment: Нашёл информацию, что если наш double слишком велик для помещения в int, то при приведении переменная получит значение `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Отсюда получаем 31 единицу при выполнении фрагмента кода `System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString((int) d));` Под short берём 16 младших бит, то есть опять 16 единиц. Старший бит равен единице, значит, полученное число отрицательное. Отрицательные числа в памяти компьютера хранятся в доп. коде, при переводе из которого в прямой мы получим заветную -1. Я всё правильно понял?

Comment: И ещё вопрос: почему при приведении из `double` в `int` переменной в случае нехватки места присвоится `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, а при приведении из целочисленного типа в другой целочисленный переменная просто получит количество младших бит, необходимых финальному типу? Почему такая же логика не работает?

Comment: По первому да. После переполнения машина меняет значение на максимальное. По второму я привел примеры на этот счёт нужно почитать литературу немного. Сегодня не нашел достаточно времени. Завтра покопаю

Comment: Спасибо, что помогаете разобраться :) Если что-нибудь узнаете на этот счёт, пожалуйста, дайте знать.

Comment: Ну как никак сообщество хоть и не знакомы. Найду напишу